# Firebase phone auth verification limit

Tags: android, ios, firebase, web, firebase-authentication

Firebase says that for the Spark plan the limit for phone auth verification is 10k / month.

So, suppose 1000 users login using phone auth 5 times each (after signing out each time) then will it be counted as 5000 verifications or 1000 verifications?

Comment: Is this limit per month or per day ?

Answer (score 2):

I just tried and tested it out. The billing is calculated on the basis of the **total number of phone verifications** by the users. So in your case, if all 1000 users sign-out and then sign-in again and repeat this over 5 times, you'd have used **5000** verifications out of your monthly verification limit.

The number of verification SMS sent is however irrelevant and is not counted towards your monthly verification usage.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: How can we increase the limit of this? I have the blaze plan, and we should be paying on verification, still it is blocked.

Comment: What do you mean blocked?

Answer (score 0):

It will be counted only 1000 verifications because they keep track of the number registered.

Comment: are sure about this details?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion:

The number of sent messages (sms) is considered, So **5000** is true.